# RegEx greedy matching and backtracking

Tags: regex, regex-greedy

I am trying to gain better understanding of the backtracking process for greedy matching.

Requesting your help to confirm/correct my assertion mentioned below.

Regex: `.*man`

Test string: `ithmati`

I used regex101.com debugger and captured the first 11 steps of the matching process into a pic which I have attached to this post.

**Assertion:** In step 9, the reason why engine backtracked in the test string to "h" is because it had already backtracked to "m" in step 6 so the next best course is to go further back.

[Pic: Greedy backtracking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mhnHG.png)

[Pic: Non-greedy backtracking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4RPk.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The steps you showed seem like exactly what I would have expected here.  In step #9, the engine fails to find the letter `n` in the next position, to complete the match for `.*man`.  Since `.*` is greedy, the engine starts at the *end* of the string, and tries to find the *latest* occurrence of `man` first.  Since this did not happen with the first `ma` match, the engine falls backwards to try find an earlier match.  It does not find any earlier chance for a match, so the pattern then fails without a match.

Comment: In the non-greedy version, when the engine backtracks to `m` in the pattern, it backtracks or starts at `a` in the string however in the greedy version it backtracks to `h`. So trying to understand why it did not start at `a` in the string after backtracking in step 9 to `m` in the pattern. I think what you stated confirms my assertion.

Comment: I presume that by "non-greedy" version, you mean the pattern `.*?man`.  For this pattern, the engine will try to match the _first_ occurrence of `man`.  So, it will also encounter `ma` in your test string.  But as it is coming from left to right, it will forward track to the right, not left.

Comment: Yes, Tim - I meant `.*?man`, sorry, I should have stated it in my original comment. I have added the non greedy pic to my original post. I think your answer and my assertion are stating the same.